# Getting difference from all possible pairs from a list Python

Tags: python, list

I have an int list with unspecified number. I would like to find the difference between two integers in the list that match a certain value.

```
#Example of a list
intList = [3, 6, 2, 7, 1]

#This is what I have done so far

diffList = []

i = 0
while (i < len(intList)):
    x = intList[i]

    j = i +1
    while (j < len(intList)):
        y = intList[j]

        diff = abs(x-y)
        diffList.append(diff)

        j += 1
    i +=1

#Find all pairs that has a difference of 2
diff = diffList.count(2)
print diff
```

Is there a better way to do this?

EDIT: Made changes to the codes. This is what I was trying to do. What I want to know is what else can I use besides the loop.

Comment: the code you posted doesn't do anything to match values, it just prints?

Comment: @CameronSparr -- while you're correct, I often do stuff like this when proto-typing.  Usually I'll end up replacing `print` with `yield` later on :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

seems like a job for [`itertools.combinations`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)

```
from itertools import combinations
for a, b in combinations(intList, 2):
   print abs(a - b)
```

You could even turn this one into a list comprehension if you wanted to :)

```
[abs(a -b) for a, b in combinations(intList, 2)]
```

Comment: I was looking for something like that. I got the part almost right except I wasn't sure how I can get the i and j = i+1 part right since they're from the same list. I see that combinations probably handled that. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

```
int_list = [3, 6, 2, 7, 1]
for x in int_list:
    for y in int_list:
        print abs(x - y)
```

Comment: For what it's worth, this doesn't do exactly what OP's original code does.  (You'll get duplicates with this where OP took care to remove the duplicates)

Comment: @mgilson Thanks. I wasn't quite sure what the OP wanted because the original code was only printing.